# Independence of Random Variables and Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$.

If $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x, X_2 \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x)\mathbb{P}(X_2 \leq y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Really struggling as how to do this inclusion.

This may help:

[image]

Comment: How do you define indenpendence? As indepence of $\sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2)$?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @martini : I would define independence of random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ by saying that for every pair of Borel-measurable sets $A_1,A_2\subseteq\mathbb R$, the events $[X_1\in A_1]$ and $[X_2\in A_2]$ are independent events. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard argument uses the following two ingredients:

> **Proposition.** The collection $\mathcal{A} = \{ (-\infty, x] : x \in \Bbb{R} \}$ is a $\pi$-system that generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb{R}$

and

> **Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem.** Let $\mathcal{D}$ be any Dynkin system that contains a $\pi$-system $\mathcal{A}$. Then $\mathcal{D}$ also contains $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Here, a *Dynkin system* (or *$\lambda$-system*) $\mathcal{D}$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ that is closed in both complement and disjoint limit:

- $\Omega \in \mathcal{D}$,
- If $A \in \mathcal{D}$, then so is $A^{c} \in \mathcal{D}$.
- If $A_{n} \in \mathcal{D}$ are disjoint, then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} \in \mathcal{D}$.

(This definition is not the same as the classical definition as collections which are closed under subtraction and monotone limit, but they are indeed equivalent. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system).) Then we can prove the following theorem (from Section 2.1, [Durrett](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html)):

> **Proposition.** If $\mathcal{A}_{n}$ are independent $\pi$-systems, then $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_{n})$ are also independent.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{D}_{1}$ be defined as

$$\mathcal{D}_{1} = \{ A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{1}) : A, A_{2}, \cdots, A_{n} \text{ are independent for all } A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}_{2}, \cdots, A_{n} \in \mathcal{A}_{n} \}.$$

By using the countable additivity of $\Bbb{P}$, we easily check that $\mathcal{D}_{1}$ is a Dynkin system that contains $\mathcal{A}_{1}$, hence $\mathcal{D}_{1} = \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{1})$ by the Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem. This shows that $\mathcal{A}_{2}, \cdots, \mathcal{A}_{n}, \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{1})$ are independent. Now apply this result to prove the independence of $\mathcal{A}_{3}, \cdots, \mathcal{A}_{n}, \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{1}), \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{2})$ and so on until we reach the desired conclusion. ////

Now you can combine this theorem with the proposition above to conclude that

> **Corollary.** If $\Bbb{P}(X_{1} \leq x_{1}, \cdots, X_{n} \leq x_{n}) = \Bbb{P}(X_{1} \leq x_{1}) \cdots \Bbb{P}(X_{n} \leq x_{n})$ for any $x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n} \in \Bbb{R}$, then $X_{n}$ are independent.

Answer (score 3):

You want to prove that for all intervals, right? Here I will use the semi-closed intervals of the type (a,b] (it does not matter witch kind of interval you will use because all of then generates the Borel $\sigma$-field )
$$P(X \in (a,b],Y \in (c,d])=P(X \in (a,b])\, P(Y \in (c,d]).$$
But then, you just need to remember, 
\begin{align*}
P(X \le x,Y \in (c,d]) & = P(X \le x,Y \le d) - P(X \le x,Y \le c)\\ 
&= P(X \le x)[P(Y \le d) - P(Y \le c)] \\
&= P(X \le x)\cdot P(Y \in (c,d]);& \forall x,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, c<d 
\end{align*}

Now, you just have to do the same with the $X$ part.